# WCF Service multiple endpoint configurations not working

Tags: wcf

[image]As per microsoft suggest, for soap1.1, soap1.2, rest based i.e. json, xml, it can be configure from web config. So the web config will decide service based on address. But not working properly. Please suggest.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
</appSettings>

<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="PaymentService.Service1">
         <endpoint address="soapbasic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="SampleServiceBehavior" contract="PaymentService.IService1" />
         <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJson" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="PaymentService.IService1"/>
         <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingXml" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="PaymentService.IService1"/>
         <endpoint address="soapWs" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="PaymentService.IService1"/>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SampleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="false" />
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="SampleServiceBehaviorSOAP">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="poxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingJson">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingXml">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>   

 </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: "But not working properly". Which exception/error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

As you've configured multiple endpoints I think you'll have to define a `<baseAddress>`-node.

Did you already try to get that service working with only one endpoint configured (ideally `basicHttpBinding`)? This way you can try step by step enhancing your service with other endpoints.

Another good idea would be to add a `svclog` into a `<system.diagnostics>`-node which could provide additional error details. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

### Edit

Error was caused by a mistake in the configuration. Solution was putting the `behaviorConfiguration`-attribute into the right place.

Comment: Yes i did. It works perfect with either basicHttpBinding or with webHttpBinding for json and xml both. It also works in .net i.e. add as service reference. But when it calls from another platform i.e. PHP it shows soap exception. Another issue is it can't get data in request from php end while calling with rest service.

Comment: I suppose to work with Soap 1.1, 1.2 and json,xml in single service with just configuring it from web config.

Comment: Are you getting any concrete errors? If not, try adding tracing (svclog) as I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: Yes i'm getting soap exception error on php while calling the method.

Comment: I'm using 4.5.1 framework in project and they says it is compatible for multiple end point configuration.

Comment: I don't mean the client side soap exception. I'd be more interested in a service side exception which you could get if you configure tracing.

Comment: If i call it as rest from php then request data are null in request. So i need to configure it for soap also.

Comment: Ok. I got your point. Wait i'll shows you exact exception of it

Comment: Ok, so it's missing the behaviorConfiguration `SampleServiceBehavior` Can you add it? You already have a _serviceBehavior_ with that name, but it asks for a _endpointBehavior_.

Comment: Well, so you should move the part `behaviorConfiguration="SampleServiceBehavior"` from the endpoint-node to the service-node.

Answer (score 0):

By adding behaviorConfiguration="SampleServiceBehavior" in service i.e. **< service name="PaymentService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SampleServiceBehavior">** has solved problem. Thank u khlr for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

After doing this i faced another issue with rest and soap both. It was multiple end point found in service. For solving this name should be added in end point ex  < endpoint **name="wsSoap"** address="soapWs" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="PaymentService.IService1"/>.
I added another answer for if user face this kind of issue if their multiple end point successfully worked.